# Getting the title of a web page given the URL

Tags: javascript

Is there any method that will return the title of the web page given its URL?

I don't mean the title of the current page which can be gotten from doing `document.title`, I mean getting the title of another web page.

Comment: Probably the title of the web page pointed to by the URL.

Comment: Edited the question. Re-open? I don't see any reason to close aside from the bad wording.

Comment: @tskuzzy. Bad wording isn't enough?

Comment: @gdoron: The point is I reworded it so now it's a better-phrased question. So now we should re-open it IMO.

Comment: One more vote to reopen.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901760/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-a-webpage-given-the-url-an-external-url-using-jquer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the title of a webpage given the url (an external url) using JQuery/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901760/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-a-webpage-given-the-url-an-external-url-using-jquer)

Answer (score 5):

You can't access this is the site is on a different domain. That would be a security violation of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Otherwise, you could load the other web page into a hidden `iframe` and use this:

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.title;
```

Actually I semi-lied. It is a security violation to do this, but IE has a bug whereby you can access the content via VBScript. Not sure if this has been patched yet.

Comment: In any browser this should work for same domain: `var x = window.open('url'); var title = x.document.title; x.close();` It may trigger popup blockers though.

Comment: Yeah that's why I prefer iframes.

Comment: which will save time? Navigating to the URL and then getting the title or doing as you said above?

Answer (score 3):

No.

No you cannot.

Not without some extra APIs

Comment: +1, because I like those kind of answers to not real questions!

Comment: Yes it is possible if it is in the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

maybe ajax can do this, but by primitive tools, you cant! (js is client side!)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can and its very simple.

```
chrome.topSites.get(function(info){ //fetching the top sites visited in chrome
    var xyz=document.getElementsByClassName('urclassname');
    for(var i=0;i<info.length;i++) {
       console.log(info[i]);  //check the data fetched by info
       xyz[i].setAttribute("urclassattribute",info[i].title); //set the title of the fetched url
    }
});
```

Suppose my top visited site is Facebook, so the console.log(info[i]) will give the value in the browser console as:

Object

title
:
"(3) Facebook"
url
:
"https://www.facebook.com/"
**proto**
:
constructor
:
ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable
:
ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString
:
ƒ toLocaleString()
toString
:
ƒ toString()
valueOf
:
ƒ valueOf()
**defineGetter**
:
ƒ **defineGetter**()
**defineSetter**
:
ƒ **defineSetter**()
**lookupGetter**
:
ƒ **lookupGetter**()
**lookupSetter**
:
ƒ **lookupSetter**()
get **proto**
:
ƒ **proto**()
set **proto**
:
ƒ **proto**()

So basically you get the title of the website.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What the question has anything to do with the top-visited site?