# Get <title> from <head> of a url in R

Tags: r, httr

From any URL, I would like to get the text inside the  tag in its header. For example, in the screenshot below, the text "javascript - Getting the title of a web page given the URL - Stack Overflow" is what I want to extract.

[image]

I have been trying to get the header with `httr`, but it does not seem to have the title:

```
library(httr)
url_head <- HEAD(url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940241/getting-the-title-of-a-web-page-given-the-url"))
url_head
```

gives

```
Response [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940241/getting-the-title-of-a-web-page-given-the-url]
  Date: 2023-06-22 10:01
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
<EMPTY BODY>
```

also tried

```
headers(url_head)
```

but nothing there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rvest` package, which provides powerful tools for web scraping:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://example.com"  # Replace with your desired URL

html <- read_html(url)

title <- html %>% html_node("head title") %>% html_text()
```

Make sure you install the `rvest` package.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the {rvest} package for this.

We read in the URL, get the element with the CSS selector "head > title" which reads "get the title tag inside the head tag" and then we use `html_text()` to extract the text.

```r
library(rvest)

url <- "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940241/getting-the-title-of-a-web-page-given-the-url"
so_page <- read_html(url)

so_page |> 
  html_element("head > title") |>
  html_text()
#> [1] "javascript - Getting the title of a web page given the URL - Stack Overflow"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>