# How to get favicon icon/ Apple-touch icon and title of a web page using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, favicon, apple-touch-icon

I can insert a whole web page in a `div` or an `IFrame` as:

```
<iframe src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" id="iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

But I need only icon and title for `Iframe`.

I have no idea how to get only these items `favicon icon` / `Apple-touch-icon`  and  `title` of a website.

e.g. `www.stackoverflow.com`, I need only its `title` and `favicon icon`/`Apple-touch-icon`. Is there any plugin or any parser that can parse the HTML of a web page and return these?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want? What do you mean by "header"? Do you want to parse HTML from a JavaScript application on another site?

Comment: I have updated question , sorry for typo error .

Answer (score 0):

See ["How can I get the title of a webpage given the url (an external url) using JQuery/JS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901760/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-a-webpage-given-the-url-an-external-url-using-jquer) for getting the title. A similar technique should extract the favicon -- just look for `<link rel="shortcut-icon">` instead of looking for `<title>`.

Note though that you're potentially going to run into cross-site scripting issues. See ["How can I access iFrame elements with Javascript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript) and  ["How to expose IFrame's DOM using jQuery?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery) for an iframe approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901760/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-a-webpage-given-the-url-an-external-url-using-jquer this method is not working any more .