# Parse link and text from user input

Tags: php, html

How do I go about getting link text (like markdown). Say some one types

```
(Google)[https://google.com]
```

The result would look like:

```
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

Here's my current function:

```
function MakeUrls($str)
{
    $find=array('`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si','`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si');

    $replace=array('<a href="$1" target="_blank"> $0</a>', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

    return preg_replace($find,$replace,$str);
}
```

When someone types https://google.com it returns:

```
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"> https://google.com</a>
```

Comment: If you're happy to use javascript there's this: [Existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901760/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-a-webpage-given-the-url-an-external-url-using-jquer)

Comment: That's not it man.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeURLs($str) {
  $explode = explode(")[", $str);
  if (sizeof($explode) !== 2) return false; //failsafe stuff

  $name = substr($explode[0], 1, strlen($explode[0]));  //remove the (
  $url = substr($explode[1], 0, strlen($explode[1])-1); //remove the ]

  return "<a href=\"$url\" target=\"_blank\">$name</a>";
}
```

should do it