# Get site titles / descriptions for multiple urls

Tags: jquery, html, meta

I'm trying to grab the favicon, site title and descriptions of a list of external urls, ideally with jquery. I've successfully worked out to sync up googles favicon service for my urls, can anyone shed any light how to achieve this for site title and description too? Here's what I have so far to get the favicon.

HTML

```
<li><a href="http://dribbble.com/">Dribbble</a></li>
<li><a href="http://behance.net">Behance</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.danwebb.net">Dan Webb</a></li>
```

JQUERY

```
$("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
$(this).prepend('<img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons? domain=' + this.href + '">');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You had an extra space `? domain=`.
- Also, use `this.getAttribute("href")` or jQuery's `$(this).attr("href")`
- use `https` !!!

```js
$("a[href^='http']").each(function() {
   var href= this.getAttribute("href");
   $(this).prepend('<img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='+ href +'">';
});
```

```html
<li><a href="https://dribbble.com/">Dribbble</a></li>
<li><a href="https://behance.net">Behance</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.danwebb.net">Dan Webb</a></li>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

- To get the title: [How can I get the title of a webpage given the url (an external url) using JQuery/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901760/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-a-webpage-given-the-url-an-external-url-using-jquer)

**But you'll most surely run into this error**:

> ...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

**so it's not possible using JS only.**

---

### PHP to the rescue:

Since the CORS policy issue in usign AJAX directly to fetch content from websites that do not allow this - you could instead:

1. AJAX `GET` a PHP script on **your server** that will grab the external site
2. now that the content is on your domain AJAX will respond with that content.
3. parse the response data using JS (jQuery) to get the desired elements attribute values or text.

> grabber.php

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents($_GET["url"]);
```

> index.html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://dribbble.com/">Dribbble</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://behance.net">Behance</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.danwebb.net">Dan Webb</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    function grabber (url, el) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "grabber.php?url="+ url,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data){
          // console.log( data ); 

          var $head  = $(data).find("head");
          var title = $head.find("title").text();
          var desc  = $head.find("meta[name='author']").attr("content");
          console.log(title , desc);
          $(el).append(" - "+ title +" - "+ desc);
        }
      });
    }

    $("a[href^='http']").each(function () {
      var href= this.getAttribute("href");
      $(this).prepend('<img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='+ href +'">';
      grabber( href , this ); // this represent the current loop el.
    });
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I was looking to try and grab the site title and description from a url also?

Comment: Most websites will block you from fetching content using AJAX.

Comment: Ahh thanks for your help Roko, I'm looking to try and just grab a summary, first few lines of text or anything slightly descriptive for a url! I'll keep hunting, unless you know of a way with PHP maybe?

Comment: Roko how can I prepend each link with the title and description?

Comment: @JoelRosen pass the current loop element to the function like: `grabber( href, this );`, than inside the `grabber` function (inside the `success`) you can do: `$(el).append(" - "+ title +" " + desc);` - Therefore make sure to also add the `el` argument like: `function grabber (url, el) {`